# Procedure to compute the numbers which follow the given condition-

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

We are provided with 3 integers - **X , Y and P, where P is always a prime.**

We have to find integers **A** (0<=A < P) which satisfy this condition-

$ ((A+Y)^{X}-A^{X}) mod P = 0 $

For this condition to hold, the term $((A+Y)^{X}-A^{X})$ must be multiple of $(Y*P)$ .

For example -

For X=5, Y=3, P=11, one possible A can be 1, because

$((1+3)^{5}-1^{5} )= 1024-1 = 1023 $ is divisible by $3*11$.

But I can't proceed further on this on how to find integers **A**.

Answer (score 0):

We assume $X\geq 1$.

If $Y=0$, then every $A$ is a solution. 
Assume then that $Y\neq 0$.
Notice that, in this case, $A=0$ and $A=-Y$ are never a solutions.

Now, if $A$ is a solution, there is some nonzero $\xi\in\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ with $A+Y=\xi A$ and then the condition $(A+Y)^X=A^X$ implies $\xi^X=1$ with $\xi\neq 1$.
Conversely, if $\xi\in\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is such that $\xi^X=1$ but $\xi \neq 1$, then we may set $A=Y\cdot{(\xi-1)}^{-1}$ to obtain a solution.

Hence, the problem boils down to calculating the solutions of $\xi^X=1$ with $\xi\neq 1$.

> By the factorization
>
> $$x^X-1=(x-1)\cdot\left(x^{X-1}+x^{X-2}+\dots+x+1\right),$$
>
> this problem is equivalent to finding the roots of $p(x)=x^{X-1}+x^{X-2}+\dots+x+1$.

---

If $X$ is even then obviously $\xi =-1$ is a solution. If $X=p-1$, then by Fermat's Little Theorem every $\xi\neq 0$ is a solution. That said, I'm not sure there's a general 'formula' for this.

Comment: Actually the value of A>=0 and <P

Comment: That just says $A\in\mathbb{Z}/(p)$.